# How to use .net core 3.1 SignalR uses for stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, .net-core, signalr

I want to use SignalR for stored procedure. I want to do run live stored procedure.

The page needs to be refreshed. But I don't know where to run my stored procedure.
I will be glad if you help. This is important for me.

Comment: Stored procedures are running in DB server. I don't understand the connection with Signal R.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @DA he means he wants website on live while the stored procedure is executing on live as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mine is SignalR using EFCore. You just can run stored procedure in TestSignalR() function.

### Startup.cs

Add services.AddSignalR() and app.UseSignalR().

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSignalR(routes => 
    {
        routes.MapHub<YourSignalHub>("/yoursignalhub");
    });
}
```

### Create new class for hub. YourSignalHub.cs

```
public class YourSignalHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendWhatever()
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("GetSomething");
    }
}
```

### YourPage.cshtml

```
<a id="btnSend">Send</a>

<span id="spanLiveMessage"></span>

<script>
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/yoursignalhub").build();

    connection.on("GetSomething", function () {
        $.post('@Url.Action("TestSignalR", "Home")', null, function (e) {
            $("#spanLiveMessage").text("test");
            // or your code
        });
    });

    $("#btnSend").click(function () {
        connection.invoke("SendWhatever").catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });
    });
</script>
```

### HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult TestSignalR()
{
    // your code to execute stored procedure here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this worked for me. But I was making an error while converting in data. Because
model not defined. JSON serialize it solved my problem.

`public async Task<string> UpdateCustomerList() { branch_id = Convert.ToInt32(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue("branch_id ")); if (branch_id != 0) { customerViewModelsList = _uow.customers.GetLiveCustomers(sube_id); } return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerViewModelsList); }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the signalr hub when the table gets updated, you can use triggers to call the hub, the code will be something link this:

```
DECLARE @httpRequest NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @httpObject NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @httpRequest = N'POST https://localhost:3000/chat HTTP/1.1' + 
                        N'Content-Type:application/json'+
                        N'{"message":"'+@message+'"}';
EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @httpObject OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @httpObject, 'open', NULL, 'post', @httpRequest, 'false';
EXEC sp_OAMethod @httpObject, 'setOption', NULL, 'UseSSL', 'true';
EXEC sp_OAMethod @httpObject, 'send';
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @httpObject, 'status';
EXEC sp_OADestroy @httpObject;
```

> But this not a good approach, there are security concerns and also
> performance drawbacks. Its recommended to invoke signalr hub from APIs
> or from frontend.